# How to use combobox or checkbox in mvc grid filter

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc grid,where one column is for status whose values are "closed","open".I want dropdown list or check box for open and close values..when i select  check box for closed" then all rows should appear whose status is closed.
same propcess for dropdown list.

Comment: any html or code will help us to better answer you

Comment: Do you want the dropdown or checkbox inside the gridview?

Comment: i want dropdown or checkbox "inside filter" in gridview.